# How to programatically zip file through UNIX command line?

Tags: c, unix, zip

I wanted to write a C code to zip a file in unix. I implemented it using system function using UNIX shell command "zip -r filepath". The zip -r filepath command is working when I execute it directly through UNIX shell.

I have witten the code as below

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
int system(const char *zip -r /root/Desktop/hi.txt);
return 0;
}
```

But I am getting a compile time error saying

```
"error:expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before string constant"

syntax system function : http://linux.die.net/man/3/system
int system(const char *command);
```

How can I fix this?  I tried putting the UNIX command in quotations, even though it didn't work.

Comment: You need to spend a bit more time reading a good C book and tutorials/examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the compiler parses `int system(const char *zip -r /root/Desktop/hi.txt);` it starts interpreting it as a declaration of something because `int` is a type and `system` can very well be an identifier name and because of the parens and the trailing `;` it could be interpreted as a function prototype. But then the compiler chokes on `-r /root/Desktop/hi.txt` because it can't be parsed as a valid part of the function parameter list.

You don't need a declaration, you need a function call, so you drop `int` and `const char *`, and the string parameter needs to be quoted:

```
...
{
system("zip -r /root/Desktop/hi.txt");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not how you call a function in C. Try:

```
system("zip -r /root/Desktop/hi.txt");
```